# Classification for action vs informational intents in chatbots

Tags: machine-learning, natural-language

I am working on a chatbot that already has action intents i.e intents which have some business flow associated with them. Now I am trying to integrate a question answering system to the chatbot. This needs for the chatbot to identify if an utterance needs to be handled by the usual intents that the chatbot supports or should be handled by a question answering system.

This is not a trivial task as a simple classifier wouldn't help because there could be some utterances that are questions but should be handled by some specific chatbot intent vs there could be some simple statements that can be served by the question answering system.

I'd really appreciate if anyone could help point me in the right direction to integrate the chatbot with a question answering system.

TIA.